# Python Selenium Webdriver проблема с пагинацией сайта

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет, необходимо пройти пагинацию на сайте.

Проблема возникает в том, что где-то на странице 30, анимация подгрузки товаров висит бесконечно, тем самым невозможно что - либо сделать.

Эта проблема встречается только в Selenium.

Если я в браузере пройдусь сам, то будет все нормально.
В чем может быть такая проблема?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time




def get_index_develop():
    global index_develop
    index_develop += 1
    return index_develop

def get_translated_text(text):
    return text

def init_driver():
    ff = "../install/geckodriver.exe"
    # chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # # chrome_option.add_argument("headless")
    # prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    # chrome_option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


    try:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, options=chrome_option)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, chrome_options=chrome_option, service_args=service_args)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

    return driver



def close_pop_up_window(driver):
    blocks = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        "div.b-popup.js-popup >div > div.b-popup__header.js-popup__header > div")
    for block in blocks:
        try:
            block.click()
            break
        except:
            continue
    time.sleep(1)


def parse_list_projects(driver):
    urls = []
    driver.get("https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/projeler/projects")




    # Блок пагинации
    while True:
        close_pop_up_window(driver)
        refresher = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-scroll.js-search-left-content.js-preload-parent.b-preload-block.load")))

        items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.b-snippet__wrapper.js-complex__wrapper")
        for item in items:
            href = item.get_attribute("data-href")
            print("Найдена ссылка на проект", href)
            urls.append(href)

        try:
            pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
            pagination_block.click()
            print("Перешли на следующую страницу")
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                print("Проверка наличия всплываюшего окна")
                button_close = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                    "button.b-button.b-button--full.b-button--confirm")
                time.sleep(2)
                button_close.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                print("Окно закрыли")
                pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
                pagination_block.click()
                print("Нажатие на pagination снова")
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    close_pop_up_window(driver)
                    pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
                    pagination_block.click()

                except:
                    print("Pagination не найдены. Конец перехода между страницами", e)
                    break

    return urls, driver



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    driver = init_driver()
    urls, driver = parse_list_projects(driver)
    print("Парсинг проектов")

    print("Парсинг окончен. Время выполнения", time.time() - start)
```

refresher - это как раз элемент, который обозначается во время подгрузки данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хороший вопрос, интересный! Подвисает загрузка из-за того, что на сайте стоит защита от слишком частых запросов. На тридцатом запросе он выдает код `429 Too Many Requests`.

Посмотрев, что сайт выдает непосредственно перед открытием в браузере, я решил, что для этой защиты от CloudFlare каждая новая сессия - считается по-отдельности. Так оно и вышло.

Решение - закрывать браузер после каждых, например, 20 страниц и открывать снова.

Также я слегка почистил Вашу логику на предмет перевода страниц и закрытия всплывающих диалогов.

Вот, что получилось:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='cp1251', buffering=1)

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time


def get_index_develop():
    global index_develop
    index_develop += 1
    return index_develop

def get_translated_text(text):
    return text

def init_driver():
    ff = "../install/geckodriver.exe"
    chrome_driver = 'C:/Tools/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe' 
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # # chrome_option.add_argument("headless")
    # prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    # chrome_option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


    try:
        # driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver, options=chrome_options)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, chrome_options=chrome_option, service_args=service_args)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

    return driver



def close_pop_up_window(driver):
    blocks = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        "div.b-popup.js-popup >div > div.b-popup__header.js-popup__header > div")
    for block in blocks:
        try:
            block.click()
            print("Окно закрыли")
            time.sleep(1)
            break
        except:
            continue


def goto_page(driver, pagenum, url=None, attempts=10):
  if url:
    driver.get("{}/page{}".format(url,pagenum))
    return True

  try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-page='{}']".format(pagenum))
  except:
    return False

  count = 0
  while count < attempts:
    try:
      close_pop_up_window(driver)
      WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
          (By.XPATH, "//a[@data-page='{}']".format(pagenum))
      )).click()
      return True
    except:
      count += 1
      print("Попытка {}".format(count))
      time.sleep(0.1)

  return False


def parse_list_projects(url):
    driver = None
    pages_per_driver = 20
    page = 1
    urls = []

    # Блок пагинации
    while True:
        print("Cтраницa {}".format(page))
        if not driver: 
            driver = init_driver()
            goto_page(driver, page, url=url)

            cookies_accept = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".b-button.b-button--full.b-button--confirm.b-cookies-notification__accept.js-cookies-notification__accept")))
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', cookies_accept)
            cookies_accept.click()
        else: 
            close_pop_up_window(driver)
            footer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".b-footer__divider")))
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', footer)
            if not goto_page(driver, page):
                break

        close_pop_up_window(driver)
        refresher = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-scroll.js-search-left-content.js-preload-parent.b-preload-block.load")))

        items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.b-snippet__wrapper.js-complex__wrapper")
        for item in items:
            href = item.get_attribute("data-href")
            print("Найдена ссылка на проект", href)
            urls.append(href)

        page += 1
        if not page % pages_per_driver:
            print("Перезапускаем браузер")
            driver.quit()
            driver = None

    driver.quit()
    return urls, driver



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    print("Парсинг проектов")
    urls, driver = parse_list_projects("https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/projeler/projects")
    print("Парсинг окончен. Время выполнения", time.time() - start)
```

Вместо `next_page` используется `goto_page`, который работает в двух режимах:

- переход к нужной странице сразу после открытия браузера - через URL
- переход к нужной странице кликом по ее номеру в пагинаторе - он выполняется гораздо быстрее, так что заслужил остаться

Также при открытии браузера я подтверждаю запрос на куки. А при загрузке каждого листа - проматываю его вниз. Может, это и не обязательно - можете дальше сами поотлаживать.

Плюс, я предпочитаю Google Chrome, но, уверен, под FireFox всё будет работать тоже.

Пока писал ответ - скрипт домолотил до конца. Общее время - 1094 секунды

P.S. Первые две строки кода - для вывода кириллицы на моей консоли...

Comment: спасибо, а то хотел уже каждую ссылку открывать занова в новом окне. Я сначала Chrome использовал, но потом как возникла эта проблема, решил на Firefox проверить, но там та же ошибка. А по поводу скроллинга, я его выполняю только когда возникает ошибка. А по умолчанию в Chrome по нажатию на ссылку идет скроллинг до объекта и только потом нажатие, а в Firefox даже и этого не требуется